# Custom site config

Tags: config, admin

Is there any way to add your own site configuration or settings into the admin panels? Either a new icon on admin/settings or maybe a section in admin/settings/general.

I know you can create a plugin to do it and I can access it, but I was just wondering if there is an area there already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently don't expose either of the two examples you gave for plugins to extend.

The closest to what you're looking for is the [hasCpSection](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up#methods), which will give your plugin a menu item in the top CP header.

Comment: Hey Brad are there any plans to allows plugins to add to /admin/settings at all? It would be useful for element type settings.